# how to filter fields using contains in sharepoint search api

Tags: 2013, search, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, search-api

I was using Sharepoint Rest api and the query looked like the one below

```
http://sitename/HR/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Employee')/Items?$top=4000&$filter=( substringof('100',Title) and substringof('ARISPL',Company) and substringof('HIBIS',House_x0020_Name))
```

Now I want to migrate to Search Api as querying against Note fields is not possible in Rest API

I was able to get items from the list with below query

```
http://sitename/HR/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:http://sitename/HR/Lists/Employee'
```

but I am not sure how to add filters against fields with **Contains** and a **and** condition

I tried the below query but it didnt work

```
http://sitename/HR/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:http://sitename/HR/Lists/Employee'&refinementfilters='AND((Department:mvrla)(Title:1000))'
```

Can someone help?

I want to convert the above rest api query to search api query

Comment: Possibly duplicate http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/210151/search-api-to-get-the-list-item-in-sharepoint-online, But still i did not get any answer for this

Comment: Thanks @AbhishekKumarSeth but it doesn't have the question of using contains in Search API

Comment: Yes @vignesh, i am agree with you, actually i am also looking for answer something like that, i have tried with Content search webpart also, but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

You should try out the SharePoint 2013 Search Query Tool. It will help you craft your query and show you the results.

You can use the colon as a contains operator `:`. In KQL `AND` is the default behavior between terms. I think your query would be something like:
`querytext='Path:http://sitename/HR/Lists/Employee/* Department:mvrla Title:1000'` which should be the same as:
`querytext='Path:http://sitename/HR/Lists/Employee/* AND Department:mvrla AND Title:1000'`

Comment: I interpreted 'contains' as a search where : __**meth**__ returns __``something``__

Answer (score 2):

There is no **contains** filter

- URI Conventions (OData Version 2.0)
  http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/
- Use OData query operations in SharePoint REST requests
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142385.aspx

Search has different syntax

- SharePoint Search REST API overview
  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview
- FAST Query Language (FQL) syntax reference
  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff394606.aspx

Comment: Danny, I think he's asking for contains in REST Search not the REST OData.

Comment: Yes, link 3 and 4 point to Search Documentation, are they not correct?

Comment: The links are great. It was your statement that there is "no contains filter". Do you mean in REST?

Comment: afaik, not in Search either, you can only have one wildcard in a searchstring(?) So you can't search for ``*msterda*``

Comment: True you can't use two wildcards. But you can use `:` as a contains operator.

Comment: That is **equals** in my book, not _contains_

Comment: Nope, `=` is equals `:` is contains. https://www.itunity.com/article/introduction-sharepoint-search-queries-explained-117

Comment: Okay, never knew ``author:McD`` returns all your documents

Answer (score 1):

The KQL query to use AND operation is as follows

```
<<siteurl>>/_api/search/query?querytext='Path:Path:http://sitename/HR/Lists/Employee (Department:mrvla) (Title:1000)'
```

You should enclose in double quote if you want exact match and space will treat as AND operation.

The above code blocks works as Path starts with given value and Department starts with mrvla and Title starts with 1000. There is no contains operation in a word.

Here is a MSDN article to know the keyword search options.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee558911.aspx

Thanks,
Venkat Konjeti